# Bootstrap 4 Dropdown and Animate.css doesn't positioning correctly

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, animate.css

I'm trying to use **bootstrap 4 dropdown** and **animate.css** but it doesn't work correctly together. Dropdown opens different area. What's wrong ?

**Note:** *We solved problem.*

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right bounceIn animated" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mehmetdemiray/aq9Laaew/40435/) !

**Solution**

```
.dropdown-menu.animated{ top:initial!important;}
.dropdown-menu-right.animated{ left: initial!important; right: 0; } 
.dropdown{ display: inline-block; }
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y9zhja8n/)

Comment: `.dropdown-menu.bounceIn{ top:initial!important;}`

Comment: @Chiller **dropdown-menu-right** doesn't work.

Comment: `left: initial!important; right: 0;`

Comment: [screenshot](https://image.prntscr.com/image/l-HxHtvSQke0eBg00ldHdw.png) @Chiller

Comment: [i want to do this](https://image.prntscr.com/image/21gigFHvQT208EBuASdBEg.png)

Comment: `.dropdown-menu-right.bounceIn{
  left: initial!important;
  right: 0;
}

.dropdown{
  display: inline-block;
}`

Comment: @Chiller thank you very much. It works now.
.dropdown-menu.animated{ top:initial!important;}
.dropdown-menu-right.animated{ left: initial!important; right: 0; } 
.dropdown{ display: inline-block; }